# Valgrind not showing line numbers on GNU autotools project in spite of -g flag

Tags: valgrind, autotools, libtool

I'm working on a GNU Autotools project where I'm encountering some strange memory allocation errors. I want to use Valgrind to debug, however when I run my executable under it I don't get any line numbers or source file names. I even tried configuring so that optimization is `-O0` and with the `-g` flag for debugging by using the command:

```
./configure 'CXXFLAGS=-g -O0'
```

Then I'll run the executable under Valgrind as follows:

```
valgrind -leak-check=full ./[exename]
```

and I still only see mysterious outputs like:

```
==3493==    24 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 137 of 303
==3493==    at 0x4A06409: malloc (in /usr/lib64/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==3493==    by 0x46904A: xmalloc (in /usr/bin/bash)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you really want is:

```
libtool --mode=execute valgrind --leak-check=full exename ...
```

Comment: Ouch the downvote hurts lol. But that definitely sounds like it's a more correct answer. I need to do more reading on libtool. Thanks!

Comment: @mastershake86 if it's any consolation, I ran `gdb`, `valgrind` and other such tools the way you described for _years_ before I read an SO answer describing the `libtool --mode=execute` method.  BTW, if you delete your answer, the downvote will go away.

Comment: Hmmm I got my 2 points back when I approved your answer, so I'm evened out :). It doesn't seem I've gained anything point-wise from this one, but I'm sure there will be plenty of opportunities. Thanks again for alerting me to the right way to use libtool, and hope it may help others as well!

Answer (score 1):

Complementing on ldav1s's answer, this is what I have on my **.bashrc**:

```
alias lgdb="libtool --mode=execute gdb"
alias lddd="libtool --mode=execute ddd"
alias lvalgrind="libtool --mode=execute valgrind"
alias lvalgrinddd="libtool --mode=execute valgrind --db-attach=yes --db-command=\"ddd %f %p\""
```

This way I don't have to type the rather long command line.

Answer (score 0):

This is resolved by invoking the executable using libtool in "execute" mode as described by ldav1s and also in the manual here: [libtool: Debugging-executables](http://www.gnu.org/software/libtool/manual/libtool.html#Debugging-executables). Thanks for the insight ldav1s!